# Java: charAt convert to int?

Tags: java

I would like to key in my `nirc` number e.g. `S1234567I` and then put `1234567` individualy as a integer as `indiv1` as `charAt(1)`, `indiv2` as `charAt(2)`, `indiv` as `charAt(3)`, etc. However, when I use the code below, I can't seem to get even the first number out? Any idea?

```
  Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter your NRIC number: ");

  String nric = console.nextLine();

  int indiv1 = nric.charAt(1);
  System.out.println(indiv1);
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You'll be getting 49, 50, 51 etc out - those are the Unicode code points for the characters '1', '2', '3' etc.

If you *know* that they'll be Western digits, you can just subtract '0':

```
int indiv1 = nric.charAt(1) - '0';
```

However, you should only do this after you've already validated elsewhere that the string is of the correct format - otherwise you'll end up with spurious data - for example, 'A' would end up returning 17 instead of causing an error.

Of course, one option is to take the values and then check that the results are in the range 0-9. An alternative is to use:

```
int indiv1 = Character.digit(nric.charAt(1), 10);
```

This will return -1 if the character isn't an appropriate digit.

I'm not sure if this latter approach will cover non-Western digits - the first certainly won't - but it sounds like that won't be a problem in your case.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Character.getNumericValue(ch)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)).

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
   int indiv1 = Integer.parseInt ("" + nric.charAt(1));
   System.out.println(indiv1);
} catch (NumberFormatException npe) {
   handleException (npe);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

The modern solution uses [Unicode code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) numbers rather than the outmoded `char` type.

Here is an `IntStream`, a successive stream of each character’s code point number, printing each of those numbers to console:

```java
"S1234567I"
.codePoints()
.forEach( System.out :: println )
```

```
83
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
73
```

Show each character along with its code point number. To convert a code point number back into a character, call [`Character.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#toString(int)) while passing the integer: `Character.toString( codePoint )`.

```
String s = Character.toString( 49 ) ;  // Returns "1".
```

…and…

```
String s = Character.toString( 128_567 ) ;  // Returns "" FACE WITH MEDICAL MASK.
```

Example:

```
"S1234567I".codePoints().forEach( ( int codePoint ) -> {
    String message = Character.toString( codePoint ) + " → " + codePoint;
    System.out.println( message );
} );
```

```
S → 83
1 → 49
2 → 50
3 → 51
4 → 52
5 → 53
6 → 54
7 → 55
I → 73
```

## Unicode code point

The `char` type is obsolete, unable to represent even half of the 143,859 characters defined in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode). The `char` type is a [16-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16-bit_computing) number underneath, capable of representing a range of numbers of about ± 64,000. Unicode characters are assigned numbers along a range of about a million, too big for `char` to handle.

Instead, use Unicode [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers to represent individual characters.

We can get a stream of `int` primitive values ([`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html)) from a string, each number representing the Unicode code point of each successive character.

```
IntStream intStream = "S1234567I".codePoints() ;
```

Process each code point number. Here we simply print each number.

```
intStream.forEach( System.out :: println );
```

When run.

```
83
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
73
```

Or perhaps you want an array of the `int` numbers.

```
int[] codePoints = "S1234567I".codePoints().toArray();
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "codePoints = " + Arrays.toString( codePoints ) );
```

> codePoints = [83, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 73]

Or perhaps you want a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) object containing all those code point numbers. Here is a non modifiable list made by [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E...)). We call `boxed` to invoke [auto-boxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) feature to convert `int` primitives into [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html) objects. Then a [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html) implementation gathers the output of the stream into a `List`.

```
List < Integer > codePoints = "S1234567I".codePoints().boxed().collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

Explaining those parts:

```
List < Integer > codePoints =      // Desired result is a `List` collection of `Integer` objects.
    "S1234567I"                    // Your input string.
        .codePoints()              // Generate an `IntStream`, a succession of `int` integer numbers representing the Unicode code point number of each character in the `String` object. 
        .boxed()                   // Convert each `int` primitive to an `Integer` object.
        .collect(                  // Collect the produced `Integer` objects together.
            Collectors.toList()    // Specify a `Collector` implementation that knows how to make a `List` object, containing our `Integer` objects.
        )                          // Returns a `List` of `Integer` objects.
;
```

### Pull digits

Perhaps you want to [filter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) out the alphabetic characters to leave only the digits found in your input string. The `Character` class offers tests such as [`isDigit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(int)).

For an input of `"S1234567I"`, that means dropping the `S` and the `I`, leaving `1234567`, producing the integer number 1,234,567.

```
List < Integer > codePointsOfDigitsFromInput = "S1234567I".codePoints().filter( ( int codePoint ) -> Character.isDigit( codePoint ) ).boxed().collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

Break that out to multiple lines.

```
List < Integer > codePointsOfDigitsFromInput =
        "S1234567I"
                .codePoints()
                .filter(
                        ( int codePoint ) -> Character.isDigit( codePoint )
                )
                .boxed()
                .collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

> codePointsOfDigitsFromInput = [49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55]

We can modify that code to generate a `String` containing only digits taken from that input. See Question, [*Make a string from an IntStream of code point numbers?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57318362/642706). And then we make an `int` integer number of that text.

```
String numberComponentFromInput =
        "S1234567I"
                .codePoints()
                .filter(
                        ( int codePoint ) -> Character.isDigit( codePoint )
                )
                .collect(                                    // Collect the results of processing each code point.
                        StringBuilder :: new ,                  // Supplier<R> supplier
                        StringBuilder :: appendCodePoint ,      // ObjIntConsumer<R> accumulator
                        StringBuilder :: append                // BiConsumer<R,​R> combiner
                )
                .toString();
int x = Integer.valueOf( numberComponentFromInput );
```

> numberComponentFromInput = 1234567

> x = 1234567

Answer (score 0):

I know question is about char to int but this worth mentioning because there is negative in char too ))

From JavaHungry you must note the negative numbers for integer
if you dont wana use Character.

**Converting String to Integer :  Pseudo Code**

```
   1.   Start number at 0

   2.   If the first character is '-'
                   Set the negative flag
                   Start scanning with the next character
          For each character in the string  
                   Multiply number by 10
                   Add( digit number - '0' ) to number
            If  negative flag set
                    Negate number
                    Return number
```

public class StringtoInt {

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
    String  convertingString="123456";
    System.out.println("String Before Conversion :  "+ convertingString);
    int output=    stringToint( convertingString );
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("int value as output "+ output);
    System.out.println("");
}




  public static int stringToint( String str ){
        int i = 0, number = 0;
        boolean isNegative = false;
        int len = str.length();
        if( str.charAt(0) == '-' ){
            isNegative = true;
            i = 1;
        }
        while( i < len ){
            number *= 10;
            number += ( str.charAt(i++) - '0' );
        }
        if( isNegative )
        number = -number;
        return number;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`int indiv1 = Integer.parseInt(nric.charAt(1));`

Comment: Integer.parseInt takes a string, not a char.

Comment: heh oops
Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(nric.charAt(1))); :P
or 
Integer.parseInt(nric.substr(1, 1));
But seriously, just go with Jon Skeet's answer.

Comment: ParseInt expects String not char