# An error with for loop

Tags: java, arrays, string, algorithm

I am working on problem of string manipulation.Following is my code snippet.
I am really not sure why my code control is not going inside `IF` loop.

```
public class test{

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int searchVariable = scan.nextInt();
    int numberOfValues = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
    while (numberOfValues-- != 0) {
        String strg = scan.nextLine();
        String[] arrayInt = strg.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayInt.length; i++) {
            //   System.out.println("test 1===");
           // System.out.println("i value" + i);
           // System.out.println("i " + strg.charAt(i));
           // System.out.println(searchVariable);
            if (searchVariable==strg.charAt(i)) {
                System.out.println("===>");
                System.out.println("index " + i);
                return;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

**Input**

4

6

1 4 5 7 9 12

**Output**

output should be 4.
As i am writing this code for finding integer 4 in the third line of input.

**Problem**

Program control is not going inside the loop `if (searchVariable==strg.charAt(i))`
.Please help!!

Comment: How do you expect `if (searchVariable==strg.charAt(i))` to work? What do you think it should do? Why do you think so?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627371/java-charat-convert-to-int

Comment: Hint: what do you think is result of `4=='4'`?

Comment: @Pshemo hi, thanks for a quick reply..i updated the question...as i want to search `integer 4` in the third line of the input, that's why i am comparing it with every char at particular index.

Comment: @Pshemo i also tried it with `(int)strg.charAt(i)`. please let me know if i am wrong (which i could be)..and used `Integer.parseInt` also.

Comment: And what value did `(int)strg.charAt(i)` return? What do you think it represents?

Comment: @Pshemo it will represent ASCII of the charAt(i), my bad. But what would you suggest me in this case?

Comment: Not necessary ASCII but index in Unicode Table. You can find solution in post linked by Tunaki.

Comment: @Pshemo thanks very much!! :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is problem in your logic: What you actually want is

```
if (searchVariable==Integer.parseInt(arrayInt[i]))...
```

Answer (score 0):

When java compares different objects, it checks different aspects, one of them is their type.

For example, the char '1' is different from the integer 1 and therefore '1'==1 will return false.

```
char c = '1';
System.out.println(c==1); //false
```

When comparing char to integer you should use parsing or the method **Character.getNumericValue(c)**:

```
System.out.println(Character.getNumericValue(c)==1); //true
```

Also note that when java compares char to integer it uses the ascii value of the char, therefore ,char 'a' equals to the integer 97 and '1' equals integer value of 49: (and so on..)

```
System.out.println(c==49); //true
```